# median and expectation and determining the largets

Tags: probability

find the mean and median of the pdf $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,\sqrt{2}]$

I got the median to be $1$ and the mean to be $\dfrac{2^{3/2}}{3}$. Is there a way of determining which is largest without a calculator - I feel it should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To find the mean of $f$, we take $\int_0^\sqrt 2 xf(x)dx=\int_0^{\sqrt 2}x^2dx=\frac{1}{2}2^{3/2}$.

For the median, we want $\int_0^M xdx=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\frac{1}{2}M^2=\frac{1}{2}$ and $M=1$.

To see that $\frac{1}{2}2^{3/2}>1$, you can work backwards:

\begin{align}
2^{3/2}&>2\\
2^3&>2^2\\
8&>4.
\end{align}

In general, you can preserve the direction of an inequality if you are applying a strictly increasing function, such as squaring or multiplying by a positive number.

Comment: $\int_0^{\surd 2} x^2\operatorname d x = 2^{3/2}/3$ , but the same principle applies.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That actually changes the answer, but as you say, you can use similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show that $2^\frac{3}{2}<3$. That is easy. Start with a true statement: $8<9$ or $2^3<3^2$. Now raise both sides of the inequality to $1/2$ to conclude that  $2^\frac{3}{2}<3$ or 
$\frac{2^\frac{3}{2}}{3}<1$